# t-test on the difference-in-difference

Tags: t-test, difference-in-difference

I have sampled two groups with different means before treatment. Would it be possible to run a $t$-test after the treatment to see if the original difference between the means changed? Most of what I have reviewed states that the two sample groups have to be the same.

Comment: Can you clarify by explaining the design or a dummy data structure? Are you saying each subject is measured at time 0 and time 1, with a group indicator for membership to A or B groups? Is the time 0 measurement "preintervention"? In this case, though a paired t-test could be used - something that's often called a "change score" analysis" - the ANCOVA is a more robust and valid analysis. This is a linear model where, instead of calculating differences, you fit only the post-baseline response and adjust for the baseline response as a variable in a model.

Comment: @AdamO sure, I have two sample groups that I am trying to compare sales revenue and sold items against. While I did randomize the groups initially and worked to pair them into a test and control for equality across both metrics, I later found out a subset of both groups needs to be excluded due to an external issue. Now in the pre-period, a difference does exist between my test and control. I am trying to figure out a way to salvage a useful analysis to measure the impact of my treatment and thought diff in diff would work.